# goog.string is overridden when I use soyutils.js

Tags: javascript, google-closure

**goog.string** is not able to be used when **soyutils.js** is included in the same HTML file.

because in soyutils.js has its own goog.string that completely override goog.string <-- goog.require('goog.string').

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>codeBox</title>
    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}closure-library/closure/goog/base.js"></script>
    <script>

    goog.require('goog.string');

    </script>

    <script src="{{STATIC_URL}}soyutils.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    console.log(goog.string.trim);

    </script>
</body>
```

(ignore {{STATIC_URL}} that is for Django Server)

console.log(goog.string.trim) will show you "undefined".

That's becuase goog.string is overridden by goog.string located in soyutils.js.

**how can i get around this problem without compiling ?** (when I compile all the files .. then it runs well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}soyutils.js"></script>
```

use

```
<script src="{{STATIC_URL}}soyutils_usegoog.js"></script>
```

You can find `soyutils_usegoog.js` in the same directory as `soyutils.js` in the closure templates tarball.

The problem arises because there are two versions of soyutils.

1. `soyutils.js` is the version for non-closure users and includes just enough closure to make the JavaScript from SoyToJSCompiler work.
2. `soyutils_usegoog.js` is the version that works with the closure library and closure compiler.  It should not conflict with closure library.

[Closure Template JavaScript Usage](http://code.google.com/closure/templates/docs/javascript_usage.html#utilities) explains:

> JavaScript code that's generated by the template compiler depends on a number of utilities.
>
> Include one of these two utility files, depending on whether you're already using the Closure Library:
>
> - javascript/soyutils.js
> - javascript/soyutils_usegoog.js
>
> These files are included in the tarball you can download from the Closure Templates downloads page.
>
> If your project already uses the Closure Library, use `soyutils_usegoog.js`, which is a much smaller file than `soyutils.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Also just want to add to above answer if you are using google closure library then 
you might need to add

`base.js`

then

```
goog.require('goog.string.StringBuffer');
goog.require('goog.soy.data');
```

then

`soyutils_usegoog.js`