# Closure Compiler (soy) - [JSC_BAD_JSDOC_ANNOTATION] Parse error. illegal use of unknown JSDoc tag "consistentIdGenerator"

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, soy-templates

After upgrading to the latest closure compiler jar I am getting this error:

```
/home/users/****/js/lib/soyutils.js:1685: 

WARNING - [JSC_BAD_JSDOC_ANNOTATION] Parse error. illegal use of unknown JSDoc tag "consistentIdGenerator"; ignoring it
 * @consistentIdGenerator
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [my research](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Id-Generator-Annotations) you'll want to convert `@consistentIdGenerator` to

`@idGenerator {consistent}`.

It seems that `@consistentIdGenerator` has been deprecated:

> NOTE: There are three deprecated variants: @idGenerator, @consistentIdGenerator, and @stableIdGenerator. These map to @idGenerator {unique}, @idGenerator {consistent}, and @idGenerator {stable}. Support for these will be removed in a future compiler release.

[image: Dorthy Ann from The Magic School Bus]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am wondering if it would be a better idea to upgrade to the fresher soyutils.js but I can't find any official download page.

Comment: @san.chez I think soyutils.js is deprecated, replaced by `soyutils_usegoog.js`. Although I admit, I don't use soy myself. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139945/goog-string-is-overridden-when-i-use-soyutils-js